# Orthogonality condition for general rotations

Tags: rotations, orthogonality

I'm having trouble understanding why this condition is true. If anyone could help me understand the following statement (whether by proof or by simple reasoning), I would greatly appreciate it.

"For general rotations, $\sum_i a_{ij}a_{ik} = \delta_{j,k}$"

Here, $\delta_{j,k}$ is the Kronecker-Delta function.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rotating two orthogonal vectors gives you two orthogonal vectors, right?

Well, the vectors $e_j$ and $e_k$ (which are all zero except for their $j$th (resp. $k$th) entry which is a $1$) are orthogonal for $j \ne k$.

Applying a rotation $A$ to $e_j$ produces a vector with entries $a_{ij}$, $i = 1, \ldots, n$. A similar statement applies to $Ae_k$. What's the dot product of these two resulting vectors? It's exactly the thing in your sum.

For for $j \ne k$, the dot product must be 0, since they're orthogonal vectors.

For the case $j = k$, both $e_j$ adn $e_k$ are unit vectors, indeed, the same unit vector. So $Ae_j$ is a unit vector, which means that 
$$
1 = \| Ae_j \|^2 = Ae_j \cdot Ae_j = Ae_j \cdot Ae_k,
$$
so in the case $j = k$, your sum ends up being 1.

Answer (score 0):

A rotation, expressed as a matrix, is a member of $SO(3)$, that is, it is a $3\times $ orthogonal matrix (thus the $O(3)$) with determinant $1$ (thus the $S$ standing for Special.

For an orthogonal matrix $A$, the inverse and transpose are the same
$$
A^{-1} = A^T 
$$
which if you interpret the three columns of $R$ as the new coordinate frame axes, merely insist that these three axes be orthogonal to one another and of unit length.  Multiplying by $A$ on the right, that also says 
$$
AA^T = I $$

Now let's say that in indices, with $A$ elements being $a_{ji}$ (and the $(k,i)$  elements of $A^T$ being $a_{ik}$).
$$
\sum_i a_{ji} a_{ik} = \delta_{jk}
$$